# How to catch manual seeking in video.js?

Tags: javascript, video.js

There's a `seeked` event fired in video.js each time I've sought manually or changed with `player.currentTime(time)`. Is there any possibility to distinguish those workflows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to monkey-patch `player.currentTime` so that it sets some variable (say, records a timestamp) when it is called. You could then check that timestamp in the `seeked` handler and decide if `currentTime` had been called recently enough for it to be likely cause of the `seeked` event.

```
var timeOfLastTimeChange = 0;
(function() {
    var realCT = player.__proto__.currentTime;
    player.__proto__.currentTime = function(time) {
        timeOfLastTimeChange = Date.now();
        return realCT.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();
```

Then do `Date.now() - timeOfLastTimeChange` in your `seeked` handler to see the number of milliseconds since `currentTime` was called. If it's greater than some threshold, assume the change happened due to user interaction.

Comment: Thanks, @apsillers, nice idea. Will try it.